# Searching for birth record in Ukraine

Tags: birth-records, 1920s, ukraine

I have been searching for the birth record of my Grandfather.  He was born in 1928 in the Ukraine in a place called Maximowka.  I have no idea where to look anymore.  The state archive sent my request to Zytomir and they let me know that there is no one by the name that I requested.

Does anyone know what other Ort I can contact?

Apparently "Maximowka" is a common name.

Comment: Do you know any other relatives of your grandfather and their connection with Ukrainian places? Maybe their places of birth/marriage/death can gives clues.

Comment: Is your grandfather deceased?  If so, please include a link to something like an obituary, death notice or funeral notice. Otherwise, his name will need to be redacted from your question in order to comply with our privacy policy  - see [help/on-topic].

Comment: You really need to narrow down your search to the region. I found 21 villages named Maxymivka (UA: Максимівка) in 12 regions. Also note that some Ukrainian regions have been "transferred" to Russia after 1928, hence you may end up searching in Russia instead.

Comment: After WW II and the bombings, he had only his sister left, but he could never manage to find her.  She was in Germany, so for that I contacted the German Red Cross.  I found his ex fiancè's (also now deceased) family.  

I am well aware that the typonym Maximowka is very common.  I have sent emails to 6 of the regions.  I am still waiting to hear back from them.

My grandfather had German citizenship, but was born in Maximowka and that is all I can find in his personal documents.  I was wondering if his parents weren't part of the Black Sea Germans.

Comment: Are you sure your Maximowka is in Ukraine and not in Russia ? See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximovka).

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine  I have communicated with 6 of the 12 regions and they seem to have no record.

Comment: @Veverke  On all the documents it states Maximowka Ukraine, but as I recently heard that Ukraine was only made an independent country in 1991, I have emailed the district you suggested.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @OlgaKleynhans: good luck !

Comment: @Veverke thanks, i seriously need it :D

Comment: Kolonie Maximowka no longer exists, but it used to be at these coordinates: 50.551667, 27.95 It was a known German settlement in Volhynia.  Today it's in Zhytomyr Oblast, Ukraine and the name has changed to Zvyagelskyi District.